# Slider displays CSS correctly on Chrome but not on Firefox &IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I recently launched my new page but after doing some testing I found out that the Caption of the slider are not on the same position. I don't know whether it's the HTML or the CSS. Here's a screenshot of my problem:http://i.imgur.com/DoMf6.jpg and a link to my site http://www.unscspartanteamomega.com/home. If anyone has an idea or any tips please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of posting a link to your site, create a simplified example using the bare minimum amount of code to duplicate the problem, and give us that.

Comment: The svs-caption element is using a combination of margins, floats and absolute positioning. - seems like a recipe for disaster right there!

Comment: Thank you both of you and I'm sorry for not providing anything else. I'll look into the svs-caption Billy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is that your fonts are different. It looks like you are using @font-face fonts, but they are not working in the browsers (IE, earlier versions of FF).

The fonts have different point sizes. They are positioned in the same place in both browsers, but because the non-@font-face font's point size is bigger, they layer on top of each other.

I would suggest defining a font that is more similar to your @font-face font's point size as the next next degradation.

In your CSS rule,

**font: fontfacefont, trebuchet**

Make sure that the second font has a similar point size to the @font-face font.